# How to add a kit to Qt Creator from the command line, or other programmatic manner?

Tags: qt-creator

In my search for a fully automated install and configuration of Qt Creator, e.g. for cloning a development environment, I would like to be able to programmatically install kits. I would then reference them from a  `.pro.shared` file.

I cannot find any reference for how to do anything like this. Is there a notion in Qt Creator for how to do this?

If not, is there a way to add it directly to the files in `~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator`?

Comment: You could do some experimentation with the file that seems to define the kit attributes: ~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/profiles.xml
But -- there appears to be a fair amount of obfuscation, referencing of UUIDs that seem internally-generated, etc. so that route probably won't be as straightforward as you're hoping.
May I ask why you need to be able to programmatically install kits? Is it for something like cloning a development environment setup?

Comment: "something like cloning a development environment setup" <-- that's exactly right. It makes no sense to develop step-by-step documentation that tells users precisely which boxes to click in order to configure the project. Much better to automate that so the human can focus on the fun part of programming. Esp. because a non-trivial number of people make mistakes when following the click-o-rama that is configuring Qt Creator for bare metal targets. I'll look into the suggested file, thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't have a much better suggestion... At least for embedded Linux type of workflows setting up the kits for target vs. host is relatively straightforward, when it comes to Android it's a whole new exercise in tedium. I've always found it helpful to go through creating kits manually myself, but I prefer to have things *just so* with my setup (which usually differs from how other people on my team do things); I can see the value in being able to automate it though. Best of luck.